# Unable to publish terraform module with configuration_aliases

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I have a versions.tf in my module which establishes 3 aliases for the AWS provider.

**configuration_aliases = [ aws, aws.pr, aws.sr ]**  -> **Unable to publish**, prompted with error

> Error: error loading the module: Variables not allowed: Variables may not be used here. (and 2 other messages) (in versions.tf on line 6)

**configuration_aliases = [ "aws", "aws.pr", "aws.sr" ]** -> **Able to publish but not consume**

> A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template expressions, etc are allowed here.

```
terraform {
    required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
    required_providers {
    aws = {
        source = "hashicorp/aws"
        version = ">= 3.24.1"
        configuration_aliases = [ aws, aws.pr, aws.sr ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you doing? Why you have `[ aws, aws.pr, aws.sr ]`, then you have `[ "aws", "aws.pr", "aws.sr" ]`? When exactly is your error generated?

Comment: if the block is configuration_aliases = [ aws, aws.pr, aws.sr ] - not able to publish. But if the block is configuration_aliases = [ "aws", "aws.pr", "aws.sr" ] - able to publish but not consume.

Comment: When you say "publish" do you mean to the public Terraform Registry at registry.terraform.io? Or to a private registry within Terraform Cloud? Or something else? This error message suggests that whatever is parsing this module is not up-to-date with the latest Terraform language and so doesn't understand `configuration_aliases` (a very recent feature).

Comment: This is a hosted Terraform enterprise (private module). 

How do I update or upgrade the TFE for the new version ? (Make it understand the new features).